# OnClick function which closes one modal and opens another

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-hooks

*** ANSWER DOWN BELOW***

I need help with a bunch of things. I need to close one modal {body} with an onclick function which will then open a new modal {bodytwo}. Eventually this will lead to seamless opening and closing, back and forth. What's happening at the moment is that {body} is still open when I use my current onClick function which is to open {bodyTwo}.  I thought I was close but I'm completely stuck. I'm relatively new to React so any tips or nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

```
function FormModal() {

    const classes = useStyles()

    const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => {
        setLogin(false)
    }

    const [signUp, setSignUp] = useState(false);

    const handleSignUpClose = () => {
        setSignUp(false)
    }

    const body = (
        <div>
                <Link onClick ={()=> setSignUp(true) && setLogin}
                onClose={handleClose}>
                SIGN UP</Link>
                
               
            </div>
    );

    const bodyTwo = (
        <div className="Form">
            <SignUp />
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <>
        <div>
        <Link onClick ={()=> setSignUp(!signUp)}>
        <i className="fa fa-user-circle" /> {signUp? 'Function': 'Register'} 
        </Link>

            {signUp? (
                <Modal open ={signUp} 
                onClose={handleSignUpClose} 
                className={classes.modal}
                onEscapeKeyDown={handleSignUpClose}>
                    {bodyTwo}
                </Modal>
            ) : (
                <Modal close = {signUp}></Modal>
            )}
        
        </div>
        <div>
        <Link onClick ={()=> setLogin(!login)}>
        {"|"}{login? 'Log Out': 'Log In'}
        </Link>

            {login? (
                <Modal open ={login} 
                onClose={handleClose} 
                className={classes.modal}
                onEscapeKeyDown={handleClose}>
                    {body}
                </Modal>
            ) : (
                ''
            )}
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default FormModal;
```

Answer (score 1):

create a single function for closing and opening modal and mutate the value in that single function.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help! What do you mean by mutate?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out and I'm starting to think I have a bit of a problem with trying to over think things.

All I needrf to do was add another function which opened one and closed the other at the same time. Add this to the onClick function in the body and voila, no more stacking modals!

```
const OpenLogCloseSign=()=>{
    setLogin(true);
    setSignup(false);
    //closes signup and opens login, used for internal links
}
```